# Help me find the algorithm name - quantify difference between two words

Tags: cpu-word, distance

I know there is an algorithm for seeing how "close" two words are together. The idea is that this algorithm adds 1 point to the score for every single letter addition or subtraction that is necessary to transform one word into the other. The lower this score, the "closer" the two words are together.

For example, if we take the word "word" and "sword", their distance is 1. To go from "word" to "sword" all you have to do as add an "s" in the beginning.

For "week" and "welk" the distance is 2. You need to subtract the "e" and add an "l".

I remember this algorithm is used for sorting the suggestion list in spell-checkers. I cannot recall the name of this algo.

What is this algorithm called?

Comment: haha, look at all the parrots! (me included) :)

Comment: upvote everyone :) I think the most correct answers are the assertive ones... so the ones that say 'this is it' rather than 'i think you mean...', since it clearly is the correct answer the others must know more... right? :)

Comment: At least when you see 5 different people give the same answer that it must be correct.

Comment: I wish I could accept all these answers :) Thank you for the quick answers. Next time I'll make it tougher.

Comment: oh, and it appears I answered first hehe

Comment: +1 @ ChaosPandion... too true.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: I am not sure Galileo Galilei would have agreed... but it somehow seems to work on SO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Is it just me or is this simple algorithm great?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds a lot like the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Answer (score 4):

[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Answer (score 4):

Levenshtein distance

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: Heh, that didn't take long! :)