# Good algorithm for matching names?

Tags: facebook, algorithm, list, matching, string-matching

I'm developing an app for mobile phones that syncs the contacts with the facebook account. 
So basically I have a list of my contacts names and a list of my facebook friends and I want to get the best possible matching between the two lists. Of course i can write something basic myself, but maybe there is a known algorithm out there that gets really good results.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: oh, there is an old question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780257/help-me-find-the-algorithm-name-quantify-difference-between-two-words

Answer (score 4):

[Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)

Answer (score 2):

You might find the results the MITRE name matching challenge interesting.

http://www.mitre.org/work/challenge/