# Clustering Data

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis

I have millions of names stored in my database these names are nothing but customer names,
I Have to cluster names which are phonetically similar to each other internally,
one approach that i am using is matching each name with some selective similar names fetched from database based on sound-ex,meta-phone,initials..etc
But it is very slow ,
now i am thinking about generating unique id for each names and clustering similar unique ids,
but i am not able to generate unique ids.
there Names are Indian names and written using English Alphabet.
Is there any algorithm for clustering similar names.
please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946192/good-algorithm-for-matching-names

Answer (score 0):

The key problem here is "phonetically similar".  You'd need to know how to generate a unique ID from phonemes.

You don't say which language and alphabet these names are stored in.

Maybe the problem has more in common with speech synthesis algorithms:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/netfxbcl/thread/b6b88747-9616-462e-9cf6-78c19da32f38

Or this one for Java:

http://voce.sourceforge.net/