# Count the same number of characters between two cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new, not a first time user, but maybe been here once before.

I have a huge list of names to check if they have duplicates.

The problems is that sometimes the same name is spelled differently for the same person in the list.

So, I'd like to check the first letters of a cell to see if they are the same.

For example, here's a made-up list:

```
 A1 John Doe
 A2 John Dowe
 A3 John Dove
```

Is there an Excel function I can use that will tell me how many characters are the same from the cell above it?

So, in the example above the cells where the formula would be, would display:

```
A1 John Doe B1 0 (or "NA" or "REF" because there's no cell to compare to above it)
 A2 John Dowe B2 7 
 A3 John Dove B3 7
```

Because both A2 and A3 share 7 characters with the cell above them... I hope this is easy to understand.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good algorithm for matching names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946192/good-algorithm-for-matching-names)

Comment: Wow... I'm in over my head, but you may be right, I just wouldn't know how to implement any of that in Excel... Thanks...

Comment: I've shined a flashlight down that hole, I think there are some VB/VBA sample implementations if you look far enough. I don't have it any more, but a guy I used to work with implemented the Levenshtein distance algorithm. It was slow to execute, but it wasn't horribly difficult code. I've not done it because I've been redirected in another direction for now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946192/good-algorithm-for-matching-names). It's asking about name matching under a different situation, but there are plenty of good examples of how to do it listed there.

It's a pretty deep rabbit hole depending on how intense and in-depth you want to get.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it is looking like a very complicated thing I'm looking for... Thanks!...

Answer (score 0):

**You are NOT giving us enough info.**

In your case, A1 ("John Doe") contains two "o" characters. Because of that, the cell below, A2 ("John Dowe") will have only 6 characters in common.

**IF** what you mean by "same character" is same character in the same position, then you still have got a problem, between A1 and A2.

John Do**e**
John Do**w**e

"w" and "e" don't match. Only 6 characters is same.

**Provides us more info!**

**EDIT #1**
Copy and paste this code in the Module

```
Function compareCells(ran As Range) As Variant
Dim numSame As Integer

Dim c As Integer
Dim r As Integer
c = ran.Column  'find selected column
r = ran.Row     'find selected row

Dim a As String
Dim b As String
a = Worksheets("Ark1").Cells(r - 1, c).Value    'string of the cell above
b = Worksheets("Ark1").Cells(r, c).Value        'string of the current cell

Dim aLen As Integer
aLen = Len(a)      'check the length of the a string


Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To aLen
    If Mid(a, i, 1) = Mid(b, i, 1) Then 'if chars in same pos are equal...
        numSame = numSame + 1
    End If
Next

compareCells = numSame

End Function
```

**EDIT #2**

```
Function compareCells(ran As Range) As Variant
Dim numSame As Integer

Dim c As Integer
Dim r As Integer
c = ran.Column  'find selected column
r = ran.Row     'find selected row

Dim a As String
Dim b As String
a = ActiveSheet.Cells(r - 1, c).Value    'string of the cell above
b = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c).Value        'string of the current cell

Dim aLen As Integer
aLen = Len(a)      'check the length of the a string


Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To aLen
    If Mid(a, i, 1) = Mid(b, i, 1) Then 'if chars in same pos are equal...
        numSame = numSame + 1
    End If
Next

compareCells = numSame

End Function
```

Use `=compareCells()` and select *only* the cell you want to compare with the cell above

Comment: Ok, let me try... I do mean that the function would compare the same character in the same position... but I'm counting the space character as a character, too... so that's why John Doe and John Dowe I count as having 7 characters the same, they both start out with John_Do, if you count the space as a character... By looking at the length of a string and setting up a column beside it which would count the number of characters that are the same, I could set up a ratio which would help me find similar names to look at more closely...

Comment: Wow! I'm impressed, but I must be doing something wrong. I was anxious to try this out but I can't figure out why it won't work for me. I'm new at this, though, so let me ask you a couple of dumb questions. I inserted this into a 'Module' in Excel, then I tried to use the formula compareCells() by inserting BG116 within the parentheses, because that was my test cell. BG116 has cells on top and below it but I'm getting a #VALUE! error. The cell above BG116 has a name that begins with Tom_ and so does BG116. I know I must be doing something wrong... What should I be doing?... Thanks again...

Comment: I think I know where the problem is. I gave names to my worksheets, and you didn't. I have now updated the code. See my EDIT #2. The error will be gone.